# Why iOS cannot get subviews property for class UIView using class_getProperty function?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, runtime, subviews

I want to get the information about `subviews` property of class `UIView`:

```
objc_property_t property = class_getProperty([UIView class], "subviews");
```

But, it returns nil? I think it is so strange. Could someone explain this behavior to me?

Comment: weird... `valueForKey:` is showing up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird.  If you use `-valueForKey:`, it can clearly be shown to exist.  This used to be a bug with the old LLVM clang compiler in Xcode 3.2.3, where properties in categories (yes, it is declared in a category on UIView) wouldn't get recognized by the runtime, and there was even a bug report filed [here](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7398) about it.  I know recent versions of Xcode have been having trouble with categories of late...

Comment: I can't reproduce it with my own classes... definitely not that old bug (thought it was, but it's not). I wonder if UIView.h might be a lie. It's possible they didn't actually compile it against that header (seems crazy, but heh...)

Comment: I can reproduce it on my machine running Xcode DP2.  You might be right though, however, I'm inclined to think it's a compiler bug.

Comment: I'm use Xcode 4.3.3. So properties in categories is also be show in the property list of runtime. But subviews property in the document is  missing.

Comment: Add the `-all_load` and `-ObjC` linker flags to your project... I don't know, it's a hunch.

Comment: I have do it. It is same and return nil. My god, the documentation and  the header file is a joke?

Comment: They must be using some kind of `#include_next` then.  I don't know what to say, other than file a bug report.

Comment: Note that `valueForKey:` and "property" are completely unrelated. The method `subviews` absolutely exists. It just isn't a "property." It'll show up if you `class_copyMethods()`. It's of course possible that there was a compiler bug at the time UIView was compiled. So far I haven't been able to reproduce this effect with my own classes (i.e. without UIView). CodaFi, were you saying you could? I certainly can reproduce it with UIView.

Answer (score 0):

I just write a test code:

```
@interface Cat : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger         age;
    @property (nonatomic, readonly, copy)   NSArray *subviews;
@end
```

It is ok. So Apple maybe be do so magic on it I guess.

Comment: Test it with a category.  It must be a category.

Comment: I tested using category, like
    interface Cat (UIViewSimuate)
    property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *subviews;
    end
and use NSClassFromString function to get the class, not including the header file. It is the same, the subviews appears in the property list.